# Trouble starting SonarQube

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Whenever I try to start SonarQube using `systemctl start sonar` it takes about 1 minute and then it says *Job for sonar.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status sonar.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.* The `journalctl -xe` prints almost 1000 lines of just alternating sessions opened and closed as below. SonarQube is set to run as user "sonarqube". I am running it on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux system.

```
Aug 01 12:34:50 localhost.localdomain su[12181]: (to sonarqube) sonarqube on none
Aug 01 12:34:50 localhost.localdomain su[12181]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user sonarqube by (uid=1001)
Aug 01 12:34:12 localhost.localdomain su[22192]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user sonarqube
```

If I navigate to the bin/linux-x86-64 directory and start SonarQube using `./sonar.sh start` it says:

```
/app/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/app/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/app/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/app/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/app/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
/app/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/app/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/app/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/app/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/app/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The `/etc/systemd/system/sonar.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=SonarQube
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

ExecStart=/app/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
ExecStop=/app/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop

User=sonarqube
Group=sonarqube
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have tried pretty much everything to do with resources. I have increased the kernel limit in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Running `ulimit -a` gives:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7257
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 7257
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

My `/etc/security/limits.conf` looks like this:

```
sonarqube soft nofile 10024
sonarqube hard nofile 65535
sonarqube soft nproc  2047
sonarqube hard nproc  16384
```

In `/etc/pam.d/login` I have added the following line:

```
session    required     pam_limits.so
```

In `/etc/profile.d` I have added:

```
if [ $USER = "sonarqube" ]; then
    if [ $SHELL = "/bin/ksh" ]; then
        ulimit -p 16384
        ulimit -n 65536
    else
        ulimit -u 16384 -n 65536
    fi
fi
```

In `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` I have set `UserTasksMax=16000`.

Any suggestions on what could be stopping SonarQube from starting?

Comment: Are you sure this is SonarQube related? See [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/543503)

Comment: You're right that it probably has to do with the number of processes allowed, but I'm having trouble configuring it. `ulimit -u -S` and `ulimit -u -H` gives me 7257 for both as a limit for number of processes. Even though I've changed `/etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf` and `/etc/security/limits.conf` to have unlimited nproc for all users it still shows 7257 as the limit.

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to increase the nproc limits, but the result is exactly the same as in my original post.

Comment: Maybe reading the [Requirements](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/) page can help you; read the platform notes section.